# Expresso Store: Order a single modifier in the store product tag

Tags: expresso-store

I'm trying to order a product that has one or more modifiers. I added a modifier which let's the user order a box or bag of a specific product. Now I'd like to be able to purchase that modifier with a push of a button. So I can show both modifiers with an amount, the modifier name and the order button to add it to the cart. Is such a thing possible?

```
{modifiers}
{if modifier_type == 'var_single_sku'}
{modifier_options}
                <table border="0">
                    <thead>
                        <th colspan="2">{option_name}</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" value="{option_id}" name="{modifier_input_name}">
                                <input type="text" size="2" id="frm-order-number" value="1" name="item_qty" data-required="true">
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="submit" title="Orderww" value="Add" title="Add to cart"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
{/modifier_options}
{/if}
{/modifiers}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a product has more than one modifier then this wouldn't be possible as you'd need the user to select the options. A size modifier and a colour modifier for instance present two different choices so you couldn't have an individual quantity field or button for each one.

If you *did* just have one modifier per product however then it may be possible to use the [Product Form tag](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/product_form_tag.html) which allows the customer to specify quantities for more than one product at a time and then add them all to the cart at once. It's primary use however, is intended for individual products so it would take a little creative templating and possible a query or two to get it to work with modifiers of the same product.

Answer (score 0):

As Ian mentioned it is not possible out of the box unless you get very creative. If you build a query that grabs the particular SKUs for each product variation in theory you could have a quantity field for each variation. [Direct access to exp_store_stock exp_store_stock_options tables via Expresso Store tags?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/direct-access-to-exp-store-stock-exp-store-stock-options-tables-via-expresso-sto) briefly touches on it as does [Exp:resso Store form created by products tag - I just want to submit a single SKU](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6508/expresso-store-form-created-by-products-tag-i-just-want-to-submit-a-single-sk/6549#6549)